# Prestashop smarty is not removing the cache

Tags: smarty, prestashop

In prestashop I wanted to customize the default bankwire payment module. I have changed many things there in the payment.php file which is working file, but when I tried to change the smarty file(payment_execution.tpl) it did not showed any changes. I tried to remove cache from the cache folder then I tried every process which tells to remove cache, disable cache from the store. But it did not showed the changes in the frontend. I also made the same changes inside prestashop theme folder (themes/default-bootstrap/module/bankwire) but still it did not showed the changes. So can someone tell me what's the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Delete everything inside `cache/smarty/cache` and `cache/smarty/compile`
Set the option `Template compilation` in `ADVANCED PARAMETERS > PERFORMANCE`
to `Recompile templates if the files have been updated`
Search for all files named `payment_execution.tpl` in PrestaShop
If it doesn't work you'll need to check the file `modules\bankwire\controllers\front\payment.php` and follow the instruction `$this->setTemplate('payment_execution.tpl');` step by step to see the path of the `tpl` (you will need a php debugger for that)